# Suggest a good book or reference on graded modules over polynomial rings

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-modules

I am looking for reference books or papers on graded modules over the polynomial ring $k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$. Any good commutative algebra text like Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* already contains a great deal on this topic. But I am interested in books which deals specifically with theory of graded modules over polynomial rings.

Comment: Usually such books deal with graded modules over a graded ring.

Comment: @user26857 Yes but the theory differs. E.g any graded projective module over the polynomial ring (over a field) is decomposable. Replace polynomial ring by a graded ring and this result is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by *decomposable*?

Comment: @user26857 I meant free. Sorry about the wrong terminology. Eventually I want to study the sheaves and vector bundles (related to graded modules) over projective space.  The word decomposable is used in vector bundles setting.

Comment: Finitely generated projective graded modules are free over finitely generated graded algebras over a field. (In fact, if graded Nakayama can be applied.)

Comment: Bruns and Herzog have a section in their book. It is quiet through. Also, Tom Marley has a note available online.

Comment: @user26857 Yes if graded Nakayama can be applied. But even then there are some differences in the theory e.g. Hilbert's syzygy theorem is not available (in general) for finitely generated graded modules over any graded ring.